# need an explanation to the with AttributeError 'int' object has no attribute error in my code

Tags: python

Problem with adding integers

tried setting the number to a list and adding the index values but they did not ad even though they were previously defined as an integer

```
number=int(input("What is your number ?"))
print(number[0]+number[1]+number[2])
```

Comment: The traceback you get should show which line the error was on.  The question is was it from the first line or the second.  It would probably be easier to tell for sure with the full message (in the title you cut it off with "has no attribute" without giving the name of the attribute in question; probably better to put the full error in the body of the question).

Comment: That said `int()` converts whatever it's passed to an integer; if it's a string that does not represent a valid integer then you'll get an exception here.  Meanwhile, if the first line succeeds (`number` is an `int`) then the second line is sure to fail because then you do `number[0]` on `int`, which does not support item access (it's just a single integer).

Answer (score 0):

I think `number` is a string, if you do `input("What is your number ?")` and if you use whitespace, it should look like:

number = "1 2 3"

If you need to sum these numbers, you simply do:

```
sum(int(x) for x in number.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably easier to do that indexing on a string. You cannot index an int in Python as a list.

```
number = str(input("What is your number ?"))
print(int(number[0]) + int(number[1]) + int(number[2]))
```

Sample run:

```
What is your number ? 
543
```

output:

```
12
```